# validation of password using ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I want to validate password using `ng-pattern`. I use the same regular expression in my model and it works. I want to display error message if password is not valid (at least 7 characters, one of them must be number).

I've added regular expression to `ng-pattern`, but it only shows error message, if password is shorter than 7 characters (because I use ng-minlength), and it doesn't show, if password is also in bad format. Can someone help me to figure out why it happens?

**Model:**

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{7,}$", ErrorMessage = "Máte příliš krátké heslo (minimum je 7 znaků), popř. vaše heslo není ve správném tvaru.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zadejte prosím Vaše heslo.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

**Registration.cshtml:**

```
    <input type="password" style="width: 600px" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password" ng-pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(? =.*[A-Z])(? =.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{7,}$" ng-model="User.Password" ng-minlength="7" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
                    <span class="error" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$error.required">Zadejte prosím Vaše heslo.</span>
                    <span class="error" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && (form.Password.$error.minlength || form.Password.$error.pattern)">Máte příliš krátké heslo (minimum je 7 znaků), popř. vaše heslo není ve správném tvaru.</span>
                    <span class="success" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$valid">Vaše heslo má dostatečnou délku a je ve správném tvaru.</span>
```

Comment: They're not *quite* the same though, are they? You have a space between `?` and `=` in a couple places in the `ng-pattern`....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use `/` before and after your regex, and as pointed out by @MikeMcCaughan, remove any spaces  in the positive lookahead. For example, change `(? =` to `(?=`

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{7,}$/"
```

Comment: See my comment on the question. The spaces in the positive lookahead syntax make the regex do something different.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, you're right. I updated my answer, and pointed out that too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change pattern to `/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{7,}$/`

```
<input type="password" style="width: 600px" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{7,}$/" ng-model="User.Password" ng-minlength="7" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
                <br/>
                <span class="error" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$error.required">Required</span>
                <span class="error" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$error.minlength">Mini 7 characters</span>
                <span class="success" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$error.pattern">Invalid</span>
```

Have a look at demo link https://plnkr.co/edit/Xo1qfEHS2NrdUHyHDjml?p=preview

Comment: Now it shows error message, if password is shorter than 7 characters, but if password is 7 chars long or longer and if it is in good format (7 or more chars, one of chars must be number), it does not working.

Code is in this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/6Wy7j260S3Zb1x9MUVer?p=preview